# Css-what kinds of "IF" statements there are?

Tags: css

I'm dealing with crossbrowser issues... So I׳m looking for the best and clean CSS
One of the most important issues is the "IF" statements for each browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this page:

http://www.conditional-css.com/usage

It contains every information you'll need.

Comment: Is this conditional CSS is something that requires installation on the web server?  It's not something that works completely client side?

Comment: The only "conditional CSS" that exists is IE's "conditional comments" mentioned by you. I was trying to give more broad answer.

Comment: Gotcha - It's an interesting solution!

Comment: It's a great solution mate! It helped me a lot! Another question is...Is this CSS code suppotrs all the browsers and is it works in CSS3?

Comment: AFAIR, it can only tell you what will be supported, what actually IS supported depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

CSS, in and of itself, does not have "if statements".

Internet Explorer browsers do have [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) which provide a simple way to deliver code (HTML, CSS or JavaScript) to different versions of IE.

Other browsers don't really have anything like that, though there are browser vendor specific declarations like [-moz-border-radius](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/moz-border-radius) and -webkit-border-radius.

Comment: Thanks,mate...the solution above is more generic...for all the browsers...great solution :-)